# Image cant loading Wordpress Post & Display on Flutter App using WP REST API

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new at flutter.I am trying to develop an apps who fetch the data from wordpress Rest Api. Title & description are display nicely but image cant loading where is problem i cant fix it? Here is my whole script please check it & give me the solution.

Home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restapi/wp-api.dart';
    
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String removeAllHtmlTags(String htmlText) {
    RegExp exp = RegExp(r"<[^>]*>", multiLine: true, caseSensitive: true);
    return htmlText.replaceAll(exp, '');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title:Text("Rest API"),
          ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchWpPosts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    Map wppost = snapshot.data[index];
                    return PostTile(
            imageApiUrl: wppost["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"],
            excerpt: removeAllHtmlTags(wppost['excerpt']['rendered'].replaceAll("&hellip;", "")),
            desc: wppost['content']['rendered'],
            title: wppost['title']['rendered'].replaceAll("#038;", ""));
                  });
               }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Home.dart -- I called the title, imageurl & content following class.

```
      class PostTile extends StatefulWidget {
          final String imageApiUrl, title, desc, excerpt;
          PostTile({this.imageApiUrl, this.title, this.desc, this.excerpt});
        
          @override
          _PostTileState createState() => _PostTileState();
        }
        
        class _PostTileState extends State<PostTile> {
          String imageUrl = "";
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                if (imageUrl != "") {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => PostPage(
                            title: widget.title,
                            imageUrl: imageUrl,
                            desc: widget.desc,
                          )));
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:8),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    FutureBuilder(
                        future: fetchWpPostImageUrl(widget.imageApiUrl),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            imageUrl = snapshot.data["guid"]["rendered"];
                            return Image.network(imageUrl);
                          }
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }),
                    SizedBox(height: 8),
                    Text(
                      widget.title,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(widget.excerpt)
                    //shortDescriptionView()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

wp-api.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
    
Future<List> fetchWpPosts() async {
      final response = await http.get(
         Uri.parse("https://devsyntech.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed"),
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
      var convertDatatoJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return convertDatatoJson;
    }
    
    Future fetchWpPostImageUrl(url) async {
      final response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
      var convertDatatoJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return convertDatatoJson;
    }
```

Comment: print for the image - does this show up ?

Comment: Which images are not showing up the post thumbnail or the post content image ?

Comment: featured image cant show. May be this script are not working

if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            imageUrl = snapshot.data["guid"]["rendered"];
                            return Image.network(imageUrl);
                          }

Comment: how about you replace `FutureBuilder( future: fetchWpPostImageUrl(widget.imageApiUrl),` widget with Image.network(widget.imageApiUrl) what is the output ?